# Creating ELF  binaries without using libelf or other libraries

Tags: c, linux, compiler-construction, elf

Recently I tried to write a simple compiler on the linux platform by myself.

When it comes to the backend of the compiler, I decided to generate ELF-formatted binaries without using a third-party library, such as `libelf`.

Instead I want to try to write machine code directly into the file coresponding to the ELF ABI just by using the `write()` function and controlling all details of the ELF file.

The advantage of this approach is that I can control everything for my compiler.

But I am hesitating. Is that way feasible, considering how detailed the ELF ABI is?

I hope for any suggestions and pointers to good available resources available.

Comment: Ah yes, the old "I want to write my own encyclopedia, because then I don't have to worry about any inaccuracies in the one that's been peer vetted, proofread by many thousands of people - I can do it better" argument.

Comment: @Marc - For production software I totally agree.  But if you're already writing your own compiler to learn about compiler writing, why not go all the way and do the code generation and output yourself as well.  Could be a very interesting learning experience.

Comment: That would be the job of the linker, not the compiler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How easy/feasible this is depends on what features you want to support. If you want to use dynamic linking, you have to deal with the symbol table, relocations, etc. And of course if you want to be able to link with existing libraries, even static ones, you'll have to support whatever they need. But if your goal is just to make standalone static ELF binaries, it's really very easy. All you need is a main ELF header (100% boilerplate) and 2 `PT_LOAD` program headers: one to load your program's code segment, the other to load its data segment. In theory they could be combined, but security-hardened kernels do not allow a given page to be both writable and executable, so it would be smart to separate them.

Some suggested reading:

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1059

Comment: Thannks for your suggestion. Can you recommend any info for me to study ELF file format?

Comment: Added one link that should be helpful.